# Auto rotate portrait image to horizontal on mobile version

Tags: html, jsf

The situation is that after I upload the image using **p:upload** tag and then display it using **div** tag with **background-image** style rule. The image is showed but its orientation is changed, which is turned to be horizontal.

However, this problem seems to happen only on mobile version of the website.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import ch.ivyteam.util.Base64;

out.addressInformationBean.contract.employee.contact.contactPhotoBlob = Base64.encode(IOUtils.toByteArray(param.event.getFile().getInputstream()));
out.hasContactPhoto = true;
```

The upper snippet code is the one I use to get the image's encode. After upload, I use this base64 code to display the image using a **div** with **background-image** style.

I wonder if there is any auto rotation feature of the browser.

Comment: Is the image retrieved rotated? Or is the image displayed rotated?

Comment: I think it's displayed rotated, because I made no modification to the retrieved image.
A bit deeper into the situation is that, the image is showed portrait on the phone, but then I upload the image and update it directly to the div with background-image style. It showed rotated.

Comment: Please don't think. Verify it. I'm asking this because "displayed rotated" is absolutely not the default behavior of HTML (note that JSF is merely a HTML code generator here), so it's more likely that the client has actually sent it rotated (which is indeed recognizable on some Android based clients)

Comment: @BalusC It came out that the image is sent rotated, which has a specific orientation value in EXIF data. So on the phone, it's displayed rightly to the user but then uploaded to the website, it's displayed with its orientation value (which is 6 and there are 8 different values of orientation) [link](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html). 
I used this javascript library [link](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/blob/master/README.md) to get the file when user upload and use this library to parse meta data of the file then rotate it using CSS transform.